# MuleSoft: Payload not Displaying as Expected in Response

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio, anypoint-platform, anypoint-exchange

I'm currently working with an IT company, and MuleSoft is relatively new to me. While I've learned quite a few things, I'm encountering an issue.

My problem is that whenever I attempt to set a payload to display a specific value, it doesn't appear as expected in the response body, even when I hard code it in the transform message at the end of the flow.

What could possibly be causing this issue? Am I missing something in my configuration?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of your specific code, I'll provide an example based on my understanding of your use case. To proceed, please follow these steps:

1. Create a new project named 'mule-test'.
2. Replace the entire 'mule-test.xml' mule configuration file with the provided code below.
3. After deploying the application, you can access it using the following URL: http://localhost:8081/test.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
    http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="4e5f4a85-7fbf-4574-adfa-6bf29817a9d1" >
        <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <flow name="mule-testFlow" doc:id="e09a142b-8597-4f90-a4f7-e4df8cb158a9" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="b219dc15-d4ec-4334-80f3-c8f48bfb9c67" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/test"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="de99c1be-5fbc-43bd-9b94-7660dfef8210" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0 output application/json --- {
    "Key1": "Value1",
    "Key2": "Value2" }]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
    </flow>
   ```

Providing a screenshot while testing the application using Postman:
[image]